# How to render rtsp:// videos in Visual Basic 6 using windowsmediaplayer component?

Tags: windows, vb.net, vb6, video-streaming

How do I play rtsp:// videos in Visual Basic using the Windows Media Player component? I've added the component to a form and set the video path to a URL, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe WMP simply doesn't support your stream type.

To check if your player supports your stream, just open Media Player , press Ctrl+U and then type your rtsp URL there. Wait some time.If it doesn't play, then

1)You used old WMP component. Try to find newer component and do with it.
2)Find codecs such as K-Lite Codec Pack and then retry. 
I think this will help you very much . Good luck ;)